# Unable to filter the PrimeNG datatable immediately after assigning the data

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am working with PrimeNG datatable and Angular 4. I am getting the data from server and assigning it to the table reference.

```
@ViewChild('tableRef') table;

this.http.callDataFromServer()
.subscribe((data) => {
    this.table = data;
    this.table.filter('Growth', 'status', 'equals');
}
```

For some reasons, the filter call fails saying *'Cannot read length of null'*.
I analysed and it appears that the `dataToRender` property of datatable is still null at the time of *'filter'* call.

I tried wrapping filter call in a timeout and the below code works:

```
this.http.callDataFromServer()
    .subscribe((data) => {
        this.table = data;
        setTimeout(()=> {
           this.table.filter('Growth', 'status', 'equals');
        },0);
    }
```

Although it works, I am trying to avoid using timeout. Had someone faced this issue before and has a better solution ? Maybe someone can point me to any similar issue known to PrimeNG.